# Typescript npm library

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a bunch of base classes in typescript. I also have a webapplication written in react using typescript where I want to include the library of 'Plain Old Typescript objects' where all the data types are defined. Lets call it the 'domain.common' library.

From domain.commin I have a small npm build task that basically uses the typescript compiler and a configuration to create the actualy js code. The tsconfig.json look like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "amd",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "outFile": "npm_lib_template/bundle.js"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

This snippet using the typescript compiler gives a bundled file:
'bundle.js' and 'bundle.d.ts'. This is all fine and peeking the declaration file it seems to follow the standard for exporting typescript files.

```
declare module "BaseEntity" {
    /**
     * The BaseEntity class that contains an unique ID
     * @class
     */
    export abstract class BaseEntity {
        /**
         * The unique identifier for this entity
         */
        id: string;
        classType: string;
        equals(obj: any): boolean;
        constructor();
    }
}
declare module "BaseConnection" {
    import { BaseEntity } from "BaseEntity";
    /**
     * A base connection class that represent a link between two {@link BaseEntity} classes
     * @class
     * @extends BaseEntity
     */
    export abstract class BaseConnection extends BaseEntity {
        nodeFirstReference: string;
        nodeSecondReference: string;
        constructor();
    }
}
declare module "housing/HouseInformation" {
    import { BaseEntity } from "BaseEntity";
    export class HouseInformation extends BaseEntity {
        address: string;
        zipCode: string;
        city: string;
        country: string;
        constructor();
    }
}
```

I can confirm this in the webapplication, seeing that Visual Studio Code picks up the class definitions.

```
import {HouseInformation} from 'housing/HouseInformation'
```

But when I start the application I get:

**Module not found: Can't resolve 'HouseInformation' in '...\src\service\data'**

Also I am using npm link to link the local library to the web application during development. I cannot see what I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are your compiled js files being written to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tsconfig.json look like the following:

Prefer the conventions mentioned in the official documentation : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Specifically [tsconfig `module: commonjs` with `outDir` and package.json `types`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html).

Comment: Thanks! This was basically the correct question. With package.json neededing an entry I just used some base class and it did work like a charm! Instad of bundling all the files to one giant, it is now more structured.